# Question about performance in development mode - next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm building my first project with next.js, and it's been a crazy journey so far, and it's been great, but, i've noticed something about this thechnology that kinda bothers me.

Not onyl in the development of my app, but in the course i did, i've noticed that next.js is a litle bit slow on development mode, is that normal ? when i make the deployment it's going to be different ? why is that slow when development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

It is because Next.js's development mode has a lot of development tools that have to be run while on development mode. That's why it is slower. When you're switching to another page, that page is also compiled first - that's another reason why it seems slower.

For production mode, Next.js is optimized. To run your application in production mode, simply run `next build` then `next start`. You'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks man, now i'm not scared no more jaja, i'll keep coding my app